# Unwanted scaling on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Cant understand how to avoid scaling on mobile devices. It should work without any responsive rules like meta-viewport. Tried a lot of variants but the page initially loads magnified and becomes as wanted only after  zooming out.

here is my case http://alardeem.ru/temp/test/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tag you use

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

tells a browser about initial scale only. If you add maximum scale info, it should work properly:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">`

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Your `body` and `.navbar` have the following CSS rule which causes the issue: `min-width: 1015px !important;`
You might want to remove that rule to get it working properly